# Sampling with replacement and frequency functions

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

> You have 7 keys in your pocket, one of which opens your front door. You sample them with replacement until you get in. Let $W$ be the number of tries it takes.
>
> Find (and graph) the frequency function of $W$.
>
> Find $E(W)$. Sketch the frequency function for values of $W < 10$. Which method of searching the keys is better AND WHY?

I need help understand this question. I'm not sure how to go about it. If I did this without replacement, I would get the random variable $W_1$.

$W_1$ is $fw_1(j) = 1/7$ for each $j = 1, ..., 7$.

We also get $E(W_1) = (1+2+3+4+5+6+7)/7 = 4 = \sum_{j=1}^{f} 7j/7$

However, I can not think of a way to do this with replacement nor how to do a frequency function/graph. Any help would be appreciated greatly, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is with replacement, then one way you can think of this as having a 7-sided die and rolling it until you get a one. The this follows a geometric distribution with parameter $p=\frac{1}{7}$ with over the values $\{1,2,3,\dotsc\}$, with expectation $7$. In other words, you have probability $p = 1/7$ of getting the correct key every time you sample from your keys. You expect to it take you about 7 tries.

I'm not exactly sure what a frequency function is, so I can't help you with that.

Without replacement, you have a chance of $\frac{1}{8-j}$ for you $j$th attempt, for $j=1,2,\dotsc, 7$.

Comment: Thank you, I can work with this information.

Comment: Sure, no problem.